# MOC file generation in VS2013

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, moc

I have a project generated from a .pro file. I cannot compile it because MOC files are not generated.

- `Q_OBJECT` is used in headers for classes to be MOCed
- `#pragma once` is used in headers for classes to be MOCed

I put the verbosity to detailled, and I can see that moc is called on the right classes. Then, there is following error: `standard input(0): Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.`

Finally, compiler cannot link moc files, and build is failing:

```
8>  moc_myClass.cpp
8>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 
'D:\Things\\L_build\Stuff\moc\moc_myClass.cpp': No such file or directory
```

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have any "unconventional" preprocessor commands in your header file, and is the Q_OBJECT macro in the correct location? (Compare with some example files)

Comment: Do these classes ultimately derive from `QObject`? Is the `Q_OBJECT` macro present *inside* of at least one class that derives from `QObject`? Both must be fulfilled for moc to generate output. This question is a bit off topic right now since there's no code shown that reproduces the issue.

Comment: "Q_OBJECT is used in headers for classes to be MOCed" It's supposed to be used inside of declarations of every class that derives from `QObject`, not merely somewhere in the header. `Q_OBJECT` expands to the `staticMetaObject` member declaration. As such, it only makes sense inside of a class declaration, and will be ignored by moc otherwise.

Comment: the Q_OBJECT macro is not the problem. I have a very similar project which is compiling fine, with same definition of Q_OBJECT. i cannot spot the difference between both projects that makes the compilation fail

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solve the problem by these two steps:
1. delete Q_OBJECT and rebuild
2. add Q_OBJECT and rebuild again

Comment: For future reference: it might also be necessary to delete the `moc_XYZ` file under "Generated files" in Visual Studio, then clean and rebuild.